# SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list in while compiling ejs

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, ejs

I am getting the error: missing ) after argument list  while compiling ejs.
I tried many times, but I can't find the problem.

Here's the ejs that causes errors.
What is the problem with this code?

```
<%- include('../_layouts/adminheader') %>

<h2 class='page-title'>Products</h2>
<br>
<a href="/admin/products/add-product" class="btn btn-primary">Add a new product</a>
<br><br>

<% if (count > 0) { %>

<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr class="home">
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Product Image</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <% products.forEach(function(product) { %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= product.title %></td>
            <td>$<%= parseFloat(product.price).toFixed(2) %></td>
            <td><%= product.category %></td>
            <td>
                <% if (product.image == "") { %>
                <img src="/images/noimage.png">
                <% } else { %>
                <img src="product_images/<%= product._id %>/<%= product.image %>">
                <% }%>
            </td>
            <td><a href="/admin/products/edit-product/<%= product._id %>">Edit</a></td>
            <td><a  href="/admin/products/delete-product/<%= product._id %>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?');">Delete</a></td>
            <% } %>
        </tr>
        <% }); %>
    </tbody>>
</table>>
<% } else { %>
<h3 class="text-center">There are no products.</h3>>
<% } %>
<%- include('../_layouts/adminfooter') %>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before your closing `</tr>`, the line

```
<% } %>
```

is superfluous. The parser therefore interprets this as ending the callback function of `forEach()` without providing further arguments or closing the 
round bracket of the function call. (The error message is actually pretty clear about what's going on, if you think about it. :))

By the way you also got two superflous `>` behind your closing `</tbody>` and `</table>`.

Here's a working fixed code example you can put into https://ionicabizau.github.io/ejs-playground/

```html
<%
var products = [
    {title: "foobar", category: "things", image: "", _id: 1, price: 0}
    ];
var count = products.length;
%>
<h2 class='page-title'>Products</h2>
<br>
<a href="/admin/products/add-product" class="btn btn-primary">Add a new product</a>
<br><br>

<% if (products.length > 0) { %>

<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr class="home">
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Product Image</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <% products.forEach(function(product) { %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= product.title %></td>
            <td>$<%= parseFloat(product.price).toFixed(2) %></td>
            <td><%= product.category %></td>
            <td>
                <% if (product.image == "") { %>
                <img src="/images/noimage.png">
                <% } else { %>
                <img src="product_images/<%= product._id %>/<%= product.image %>">
                <% }%>
            </td>
            <td><a href="/admin/products/edit-product/<%= product._id %>">Edit</a></td>
            <td><a  href="/admin/products/delete-product/<%= product._id %>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?');">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        <% }); %>
    </tbody>
</table>
<% } else { %>
<h3 class="text-center">There are no products.</h3>>
<% } %>
```